# How to use service principal to create azure synapse workspace?

Tags: terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-synapse, azure-rm

I am trying to use below terraform code to create synapse workspace

```
module "synapse_workspace" {
  source = "./modules/synapse-workspace"

  rg_name  = module.resource_group.name
  location = module.resource_group.location

  prefix  = var.prefix
  postfix = random_string.postfix.result

  vnet_id   = module.virtual_network.id
  subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.default_subnet.id

  adls_id              = module.storage_account.adls_id
  storage_account_id   = module.storage_account.id
  storage_account_name = module.storage_account.name
  key_vault_id         = module.key_vault.id
  key_vault_name       = module.key_vault.name

  synadmin_username = var.synadmin_username
  synadmin_password = var.synadmin_password

  aad_login = {
    name      = var.aad_login.name
    object_id = var.aad_login.object_id
    tenant_id = var.aad_login.tenant_id
  }
}
```

and in `terraform.tfvars` file I have defined this AD login like below:

```
aad_login = {
  name = "azureuser@contoso.com"
  object_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  tenant_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

My synapse module looks like below:

```
# Azure Synapse Workspace 

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "http" "ip" {
  url = "https://ifconfig.me"
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "syn_ws" {
  name                                 = "syn-${var.prefix}-${var.postfix}"
  resource_group_name                  = var.rg_name
  location                             = var.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = var.adls_id

  sql_administrator_login          = var.synadmin_username
  sql_administrator_login_password = var.synadmin_password

  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
  managed_resource_group_name     = "${var.rg_name}-syn-managed"

  aad_admin {
    login     = var.aad_login.name
    object_id = var.aad_login.object_id
    tenant_id = var.aad_login.tenant_id
  }
}
```

The above is working `aad_login` is user of Azure Active Directory

**What I am trying to do:**
I want my `service principal` to create this workspace instead of `AD user`

I verified this documentation
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_workspace
but not able to find how to use service principle authentication to create workspace

Any idea please ?

Comment: Have you seen this documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `identity` block in your terraform code which exports the following:

`principal_id` - **The Principal ID for the Service Principal associated with the Managed Service Identity of this Synapse Workspace.**

`tenant_id` - The Tenant ID for the Service Principal associated with the Managed Service Identity of this Synapse Workspace.

To access the `tenant_id` and `principal_id`, use the below code reference:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "workspace_policy" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.identity[0].tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.identity[0].principal_id
```

Comment: Thank you @UtkarshPal-MT  so identitiy block has to be explicitly defined ? In documentation I found like below:   `identity {    type = "SystemAssigned"  }` . only possible value it says as SystemAssigned. Do you have example line how I actually define this identity block?

Comment: Yes, `identity` needs to be declared. store the tenant and principal ID in key vault and use it in code as I mentioned in my answer.